# loading part of a page with it's javascript code in the another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have a table with a button which adds some rows to the table and it works fine , i want to load their parent div in the another page via jquery Load function but when i load them the button wont work anymore

here is my html code , actually i just wrote this but you get the idea and also ignore the syntax problems

```
<head>

<script>
$(function(){
$('#adder').click(function(){
$(this).siblings('table').append('<tr><td></td></tr>');
}
}
</script>

<head>
<body>
<div id="main">
<table> </table>
<a href="" id="adder"> </a>
</div>

</body>
```

in the another page altho i have the same jquery code in the header but the button doesn't work anymore 
here is my other page

```
   <head>
    <script>
    function loader(){
    $('#loader').load('a.php #main');
    }
    </script>
    </head>
<body>
<div id="loader"></div>
</body>
```

i tride to ad jq code at the end of div so when it's loaded in the another page jq get loaded too

```
    <div id="main">
    <table> </table>
    <a href="" id="adder"> </a>
<script>
$('#adder').click(function(){
$(this).siblings('table').append('<tr><td></td></tr>');
}
</script>
    </div>
```

but still doesn't work

///////////////////////

another question :

how can i use live when there is no event ?
for example i have a plugin which has some effects on page divs and its called on the page load time

```
<head> 
<script>
$(function(){
$('div').plugin(plugin settings);
})
</script>
</head>
```

now if i add a div to the page how should i use live so my  new div get that effect ?

Comment: Use live or delegate, see jQuery docs for this

Comment: Matino is right. When you append new elements to the DOM with a `.load()` Ajax request, those DOM elements aren't bound with events written in jQuery, because they were created after the events were bound. In order to fix this you can use a `.delegate()`. Delegates are preferred over using `Live` due to speed/flexibility reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("body").delegate("#adder", "click", function(){
    $(this).siblings('table').append('<tr><td></td></tr>');
});
```

http://www.alfajango.com/blog/the-difference-between-jquerys-bind-live-and-delegate/

The big "ah ha!" moment for me learning delegates was to simply google for the definition of delegate.

> del·e·gate    [n. del-i-git, -geyt; v. del-i-geyt] Show IPA noun,
>   verb, -gat·ed, -gat·ing. noun
>   **1. a person designated to act for or represent another or others**; deputy; representative, as in a political convention.

It's one of those "computer sciency" words that doesn't make much sense until you've mastered the concept or googled the definition. It helps to know the definition before mastering the term. It was named "delegate" for a reason :p

In your example, the newly created elements added by the .load() are sort of these "juveniles" or "adolescents" that are too young to handle the responsibility of events. So when you request an event from them, the browser looks to the delegate in order to learn what should happen.

To add a plugin (your second question) to new DOM elements, you would have to enable the plugin during the load event.

```
$("body").delegate("div", "load", function(this){ 
    $(this).plugin( settings ); 
});
```

Comment: can i use it for non-event situations ? take look at my second question pleas

Comment: That's a good question. The answer is yes and no. No, because you can't do it with a 'non-event', but 'yes' because loading the new DOM elements should trigger an event (`.load()`).

Comment: `$("body").delegate("div", "load", function(this){
$(this).plugin(settings);
});` This code should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

For the **dynamically** created elements, you need to use either `live` or `delegate`, example:

```
$('selector').live('click', function(){
  // your code here...
}
```

More Info: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: can i use it for non-event situations ? take look at my second question pleas

Comment: @max: For your second question, i think you need to use live query jquery plugin, check out the docs for more info: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery

Answer (score 0):

As @matino pointed out, you should use `.live("click", function...)` instead of `.click(function...)`.

But also, you shouldn't expect the scripts from a.php to be loaded into the page you're calling `.load` from, as that function doesn't execute any javascript when you are loading page fragments.

from the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

> Note: When calling .load() using a URL without a suffixed selector expression, the content is passed to .html() prior to scripts being removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded. If .load() is however called with a selector expression appended to the URL, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated, which is why they are never executed.